# Dynamic CountIFS Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using the below formula to count an particular type of event category on a particular date.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"1-Mar-2016",$B:$B,"Carpentary")
```

To make it more dynamic, I'm looking for a solution where I can replace the specific Date "1-Mar-2016" with day of the month "1" to obtain the result. Please refer below. However this does not work.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"1",$B:$B,"Carpentary")
```

Can anyone please advise how to resolve this? Any sort of suggestions are welcome.

**Table:**

```
Date        Category                    1-Mar-16    2-Mar-16
1-Mar-16    Carpentary      Carpentary  2           0
1-Mar-16    Carpentary      Plumbing    2           1
1-Mar-16    Plumbing        Electrical  0           2
1-Mar-16    Plumbing                
2-Mar-16    Plumbing                
2-Mar-16    Electrical              
2-Mar-16    Electrical
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to go to the trouble of providing column and row header labels, then use them in your formula.

In E2 as a standard formula,

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, E$1,$B:$B, $D2)
```

Fill right and down as necessary.

[image: countifs_right_and_down]

Answer (score 0):

for this case i'd rather not think of complicated formula.

i'd suggest a helper column for formula `=Day([Date])` and use it for the `COUNTIFS` formula.